# How to determine if a DateField is valid in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have:

```
DateField dateField = new DateField("Date");
Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
submitButton.addClickListener(click -> handleClickListener());
```

where in `handleClickListener()` I want to prevent a submit if there is a validation error in the `DateField`. I know I can use a Binder and then `binder.validate()` but this form has no backing object and I just want a simple form. How can I do something like:

```
if(!dateField.isValid())
   // no further processing
else
   // process
```

I can't find any code within the `DateField` that allows checking to see if the entered in value is valid. Apparently [in Vaadin 7 you could `!dateField.validate()` which would throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30196915/39371) but this is no longer appears to be the case...

I also know it's possible to do `dateField.isEmpty()` or test for null but this doesn't work because a value is NOT required. In other words it can be either empty, or if you put in a value then it must be a valid entry.

Comment: How about using `Binder` (https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.1/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html)? `Binder` comes with methods like `validate()` and `isValid()`.

Comment: Sometimes Binder doesn't work. For example my form may not have a POJO, etc. behind it, maybe I'm just using the form to make a quick calculation on a label and don't want to back it with anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been asked several times, and as far as I know it's not possible to add validators without the binder. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42993779/474287) for a comprehensive description of the feature and resoning.

There are also discussions on the [Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/15704263) and [github](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8294), and the 2 main suggestions are using a binder, or a value change listener where you manually call a validator. However, the latter solution does not seem to work and I suspect that's because a value change event is triggerd only when the actual value changes, which probably does not happen when you type something invalid, but I did not spend much time investigating.

The [latest suggestion on github](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8294#issuecomment-301062988) requests a `binder.noBind()` method to facilitate these cases, but until that is implemented you could use something similar to the below code sample. I also hated the idea of using a field to bind the value to, so I went with a *no setter* & *no getter* concept:

```
public class DateFieldWithValidator extends VerticalLayout {

    public DateFieldWithValidator() {
        // date field with binder
        Binder<LocalDate> binder = new Binder<>();
        DateField dateField = new DateField("Date");
        binder.forField(dateField)
              .asRequired("Please select a date")
              .bind(No.getter(), No.setter());

        // validity status
        TextField validityField = new TextField("Status:", "N/A");
        validityField.setReadOnly(true);
        validityField.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_BORDERLESS);
        validityField.setWidth("100%");

        // submit button
        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            BinderValidationStatus<LocalDate> status = binder.validate();
            if (status.isOk()) {
                validityField.setValue("OK: " + dateField.getValue().toString());
            } else {
                validityField.setValue("KO: " + status.getValidationErrors().stream().map(ValidationResult::getErrorMessage).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
            }
        });

        addComponents(dateField, submitButton, validityField);
    }

    // convenience empty getter and setter implementation for better readability
    public static class No {
        public static <SOURCE, TARGET> ValueProvider<SOURCE, TARGET> getter() {
            return source -> null;
        }

        public static <BEAN, FIELDVALUE> Setter<BEAN, FIELDVALUE> setter() {
            return (bean, fieldValue) -> {
                //no op
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: date field validation with binder]

---

**Later update:**

I've been thinking some more, and if it's acceptable, you could disable the submit button if the value is null or a parsing error occurs for an invalid value. This can be easily implemented with a `ValueChangeListener` and an `ErrorHandler` like below.

Alternatively, you can save the exception message in a variable, and when you click the button check if either there is an error message or the value is null, in this order because if you input an invalid date, the field's value will be set to null.

```
public class DateFieldWithValidator extends VerticalLayout {
    public DateFieldWithValidator() {
        DateField dateField = new DateField("Date");
        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        submitButton.addClickListener(event -> Notification.show("Selected date: " + dateField.getValue()));
        dateField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
        dateField.setErrorHandler(event -> submitButton.setEnabled(false));
        dateField.addValueChangeListener(event -> submitButton.setEnabled(event.getValue() != null));
        addComponents(dateField, submitButton);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: vaadin date field validation]

Comment: That's extremely close to what I did. You basically create a fake POJO (or something similar) to bind with the Binder and then use the binder's validation when clicking the Submit button.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Yep, that's pretty much the idea, at least for the time being....

Comment: @StephaneGrenier How about the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you stated you don't want to use a backing object, I would recommend the use of `Binder` anyway. The `No` class @Morfic provided is excellent in my opinion (I tend to reuse this in many validation implementations).

So what I would do is add a `addStatusChangeListener` on your binder and enable/disable the button there:

```
binder.addStatusChangeListener(event -> {
            if (event.hasValidationErrors()) {
                submitButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                submitButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

*Omitted the instantiation of the `Binder` object since @Morfic provided a good example in his answer already.*

The reason why I suggest the use of `Binder` is because [Vaadin suggests to use it for validation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-fields.html), you won't need hard to maintain value change listeners and you could easily expand your binding with new `Validator`s if so required later on. Maybe you will want to bind the field to an object at one point after all.